# Add comma in between the Tags Display in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

Can any one help me how to add comma inbetween the tags in drupal 7.

I have inspect the code  for the following tags

```
Tags: Test bha
```

the code for this is

```
         <DIV class="tagsdisplay" >
             <DIV class="label-inline">Tags:&nbsp;</DIV>
                <A  href="http://localhost/drupal/tags/test" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel">Test</A>
                <A href="http://localhost/drupal/tags/bha" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel">bha</A>
              </DIV>
         </DIV>
```

I have used used the following code to add the comma inbetween the tags

```
              function fold__field_tags($variables) {

                   $output = '';

              // Subtract 1 from count to match $delta which starts at 0
               $count = (count($variables['items']) - 1);

              // Render the label, if it's not hidden.
              if (!$variables['label_hidden']) {
             $output .= '<div class="label-inline"' . $variables['title_attributes'] . '>' . $variables['label'] . ':&nbsp;</div>';
                 }

           // Render the items.
          $output .= '<div class="label-inline"' . $variables['content_attributes'] . '>';
          foreach ($variables['items'] as $delta => $item) {
          $classes = 'field-item ' . ($delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even');
          $output .= '<div class="' . $classes . '"' . $variables['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . drupal_render($item) . '</div>';
         // If this is not the last item, print a comma and space
         if($delta < $count) {
          $output .= ', ';
         }
         }
       $output .= '</div>';

    // Render the top-level DIV.
      $output = '<div class="' . $variables['classes'] . '"' . $variables['attributes'] . '>' . $output . '</div>';

      return $output;

    }
```

Can Anyone help me where i made a mistake.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you tried using `dpm($output);` (assuming you have the devel module enabled) to see what is being returned by the function (or if it's even called)? Why are there two underscores together in the function name?

Comment: I didn't enable devel module.I have removed the underscores in the function name, still it is not working.Can you help me.I am new to drupal.Can you check the code and tell me the class name which I gave i.e label-inline is correct or not.

Comment: make sure that $delta is numeric and check whether $variables['items'] is empty or not.

Comment: I'm not sure the class name would effect things. Is there anything showing up? I would definitely advise installing devel and adding `dpm($output);` just before you `return $output;`. This will show you a) the function is being called and b) what is being returned by the function.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who needs to do this in the future:

```
div.field-name-field-tags div.field-items div:after {
  content: ", ";
}

div.field-name-field-tags div.field-items div:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with CSS, without modifying templates or adding modules:

```
.field-name-field-tags .field-item:after {
    content: ",";
}
.field-name-field-tags .field-item {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

The only drawback is that the last one in the list will also have a comma and a space after. On the other hand, there's no messing around with .php or new modules :)

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in the module:

[textformatter](https://drupal.org/project/textformatter)

> This module provides a field display formatter to **render field values
>   as HTML or comma-separated lists.** This can currently be used on all
>   core field types (text, long text, number, list, and taxonomy
>   reference etc..) and some contributed fields.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the following template to my theme.

```
field--field-titles.tpl.php

<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item) : ?>
      <div style="display:inline;" class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>>
        <?php 
          print render($item);
          // Add comma if not last item
          if ($delta < (count($items) - 1)) {
            print ', '; 
          }
        ?>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```